# iOS compatible input type date - setting min max value

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

I am trying to set the date using *jQueryMobile* in UIWebView `iOS` app, value is set properly but the min and max attribute date setting is not working.

```
<input type="date" data-clear-btn="false" name="date-1" id="date-1"  min="2013-04-15" max="2013-09-15" value ="2013-08-15"  >""
```

And

```
$('input[type="date"]').val('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

When i run it on simulator , when the date field is selected , Date picker is visible , but the min , max date is not set.

Answer (score 1):

Setting min and max values for `input type="date"` are not supported by the simulator's safari.

You can test it by navigating to [this site](http://quirksmode.org/html5/inputs/tests/inputs_dates.html) and trying out the control. It will (probably) work on the desktop browser, but won't on the simulator's browser or in your `UIWebView`.